# How can I make my form, first name and last name to be side to side

Tags: html, css

I have a signup form where I have first name, last name, username, email, phone, password and confirm password. The problem is that the form is too long and don't look good, so I want to put the first name and last name side by side and make it shorter and make it look better. Please help a beginner out lol.

```css
    .form-div{
        margin:50px auto 50px;
        padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
        border: 4px solid #80ced7;
        border-radius: 30px;
        font-size:1.1em;
        font-family: 'Merriweather&display=swap', serif;
    }
    
    .form-control:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    form p{
        font-size: .89;
    }
    
    .form-div.login{
        margin-top: 100px;
        
    }
    
    .logout{
        color:red;
        
    }
```

```html
            
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "fname">First Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php $fname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php $lname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "username">User Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php $username; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "email">Email</label>
            <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php $email; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "phone">Phone</label>
            <input type = "tele" name = "phone" value = "<?php $phone; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "password">Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "passwordConf" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `flexbox`

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.form-div {
  margin: 50px auto 50px;
  padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
  border: 4px solid #80ced7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Merriweather&display=swap', serif;
}

.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

form p {
  font-size: .89;
}

.form-div.login {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.logout {
  color: red;
}

.form-field {
  display: flex;
}

.form-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group label {
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php $fname; ?>" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php $lname; ?>" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php $username; ?>" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php $email; ?>" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="tele" name="phone" value="<?php $phone; ?>" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="passwordConf" class="form-control form-control-lg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this kind of layout by using `flex`

```css
.parent{
    display:flex;
}
.form-div{
    margin:50px auto 50px;
    padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
    border: 4px solid #80ced7;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-family: 'Merriweather&display=swap', serif;
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

form p{
    font-size: .89;
}

.form-div.login{
    margin-top: 100px;

}

.logout{
    color:red;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "fname">First Name</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php $fname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php $lname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "username">User Name</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php $username; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "email">Email</label>
        <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php $email; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "phone">Phone</label>
        <input type = "tele" name = "phone" value = "<?php $phone; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "password">Password</label>
        <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type = "password" name = "passwordConf" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using bootstrap so you can add  `row` and put each `input` in `col-6`

```css
    .form-div{
        margin:50px auto 50px;
        padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
        border: 4px solid #80ced7;
        border-radius: 30px;
        font-size:1.1em;
        font-family: 'Merriweather&display=swap', serif;
    }
    
    .form-control:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    form p{
        font-size: .89;
    }
    
    .form-div.login{
        margin-top: 100px;
        
    }
    
    .logout{
        color:red;
        
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row m-0">
   <div class="col-6">
<div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "fname">First Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php $fname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php $lname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "username">User Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php $username; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "email">Email</label>
            <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php $email; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "phone">Phone</label>
            <input type = "tele" name = "phone" value = "<?php $phone; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "password">Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "passwordConf" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```